# Scroll bar is not showing to nav tab content bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have right side bar where it stated with nav tab and i want to show scrollbar to tab-content but its not showing i want to load dynamic data into first navtab but due to scroll bar is not showing i am not able to scroll.

```css
.right-sidebar-wrapper #r-s-tab{
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position:fixed;
}
.right-sidebar-wrapper #activity a, .right-sidebar-wrapper #locations a{  
  padding-top: 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
}
#activity a img, #locations a img {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-sidebar-wrapper">
    <div id="r-s-tab" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="activity">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="locations">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: ok so where did you want the scroll bar

Comment: to navtab content

Answer (score 0):

You try this....

```
.right-sidebar-wrapper{
  height: 100%;
}
.right-sidebar-wrapper #r-s-tab{
  position:fixed;
}
.right-sidebar-wrapper #r-s-tab{
  height: 200px; // Set this height to the appropriate size
  overflow-y: scroll; // Only add scroll to vertical column
}
```